# Error running grunt in docker: Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt

Tags: docker, gruntjs

I'm trying trying to run my project with all dependencies inside docker but I got stuck with grunt dependency, for some reason grunt fails with an error that it can't find local grunt.

I created an example of how to reproduce this:

```
.
├── code
│   ├── bower.json
│   ├── Gruntfile.js
│   └── package.json
├── docker-compose.yml
└── frontend.dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "2"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8585:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/srv/frontend
    command: grunt
```

**frontend.dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:wheezy

ADD code /srv/frontend
WORKDIR /srv/frontend
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli bower
RUN npm install

RUN groupadd -r usergroup && useradd -m -r -g usergroup user
RUN chown -R user:usergroup /srv/frontend
USER user

RUN bower install
```

**bower.json**:

```
{
  "name": "code",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "authors": [
    "Mr. No One"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.json**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({});

    // tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', []);
};
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "code",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

`$ docker-compose up
... installing all dependencies ...`

after installation, it fails when tries to run the `grunt` command I specified in my `docker-compose.yml` file with this error:

```
frontend_1  | grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
frontend_1  | your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
frontend_1  | please see the Getting Started guide:
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

`package.json` actually does include `grunt` as a dependency so it should be installed after `RUN npm install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `docker exec -it <nameofyourcontainer> bash` and look into `node_modules` if grunt is installed locally.

Did you set `NODE_ENV` to `production` somewhere?
This causes `npm` to not install `devDepedencies`.

Comment: looks like the only node_modules folder I have is ```/usr/local/lib/node_modules```, node_modules and bower_components are actually missing from project's folder. ```NODE_ENV``` is not set.

Comment: Does your `package.json` exist in `WORKDIR`?

Comment: Also put a `cwd` into your `command` to see where it is trying to run grunt.

Comment: package.json does exist in WORKDIR, grunt tries to run from correct WORKDIR, tested by putting ls' and 'pwd' to 'command'.

Comment: What happens if you go inside the container and run `npm install` inside `WORKDIR`?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `volumes` from `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: npm install inside WORKDIR works (I had to change useradd & addgroup to include UID and GID from my host so I wont get errors when it tries to write files), now I can see node_modules created on host and I am able to run grunt. removing 'volumes' helps too, but now it means if code changes I have to rebuild, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: What happens if you completely remove this from the `Dockerfile`
    `RUN groupadd -r usergroup && useradd -m -r -g usergroup user
    RUN chown -R user:usergroup /srv/frontend
    USER user`

Comment: I got the same error as in the beginning "Unable to find local grunt.". I think I'll just do npm install & bower install manually after build like you said, this approach seems to work without the need to remove 'volumes' so my source code can be changed in host and those changes can be seen inside docker.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the reason why `node_modules` and `bower_components` are not created [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume).

> Note: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

While I don't have `VOLUME` declared in my dockerfile, I do have `volumes` in my `docker-compose.yml` so I suspect this note is affecting me because both `npm install` & `bower install` build steps do touch data within the volume.

I removed those build steps from the dockerfile and did them manually after build is complete:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose run --rm frontend npm install
$ docker-compose run --rm frontend bower install
```

However, I encountered problem with permissions when running those commands above, since my newly created user did not have permissions to write to host and I didn't want to run as root inside container (bower for example will not like it without --allow-root)

The solution is to create user with the same UID and GID as the host.

I found that docker allows [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) and [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/args) that means you don't have to hardcode UID and GID inside `docker-compose.yml`, instead, they can be taken from host env variables like so and can be accessed during the build.

```
$ export HOST_UID=$(id -u)
$ export HOST_GID=$(id -g)
```

**frontend.dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:wheezy

ARG hostuid
ARG hostgid

ADD code /srv/frontend
WORKDIR /srv/frontend
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli bower

RUN groupadd -g "$hostgid" devgroup && useradd -m -u "$hostuid" -g devgroup developer
RUN chown -R developer:devgroup /srv/frontend
USER developer
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "2"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
      args:
        - hostuid=${HOST_UID}
        - hostgid=${HOST_GID}
    ports:
      - "8585:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/srv/frontend
    command: grunt
```